# DataGridView multiple data sources

Tags: c#, datagridview

**EDIT:** 
I refactored my code to make the collected item have a copy of the ID that I was storing in Collector. Thank you to those of you who read and offered suggestions!
**END EDIT**

I have an object, Collector, with two properties in my form. One is an int (ID) and the other is a list of a different object (Collected). I want to show all of the Collected objects in the list in a data grid view along with the Collector ID. The ID will be the same value for every row in the data grid, but I still want to display it.

Example: 
Collected Name      Collector ID 
A                            1
B                            1
C                            1
D                            1

When I set my data source to the list, it pulls up all the data from the Collected object, but it can't read the ID property. Is it possible to do this? Do I need to create a new object with all the Collected fields plus a field for the ID and then make the Collector object take a list of the new object instead?

For reference, this is how I am setting the data source and trying to set the column. ID is the name of the column in the data grid view.

```
this.dataGridView.DataSource = collector.CollectedList;  
this.ID.DataPropertyName = Collector.PropertyNames.CollectionID.toString();
```

The Collector class is simple, just two fields. There are some other methods, but I'm not sure they would be relevant to the question.

```
public class Collector : BindableObject {
    public enum PropertyNames{
        CollectionID, 
        CollectedList
    }

private BindingList<Collected> _collectedList = new BindingList<Collected>();
private int _collectionID = -1;

public Collector() {}

public int CollectionID {
    get {return _collectionID;}
    set {
        if (_collectionID != value) {
            _collectionID = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyNames.CollectionID.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public BindingList<Collected> CollectedList {
    get {return _collectedList;}
    set { 
        if (_collectedList != value) {
            _collectedList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyNames.CollectedList.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I am trying to add a text column (not combobox) using a different data source than the main source I have associated with the data grid view.

Comment: @user3386013 - can you post your `Collector` class code.